# auto sizing containers in css, but with a minimum?

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to have it so the frames around my content autosizes, but I also don't want it to ever have a height of less than 400px. Is it possible to tell scss that?

Comment: `min-height` would help.

Comment: There's nothing to "tell" Sass:  it just compiles to CSS.

Comment: It's helpful to have an example linked.

Comment: @t.niese Would you please list that as the answer? That is actually all I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's plain CSS man.

```
.element {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/aleget/1/edit